# How to view Lucene Index

Tags: lucene, luke

I am trying to learn and understand how lucene works, what is inside lucene index. Basically i would want to see how the data is represented inside lucene index?

I am using `lucene-core 8.6.0` as dependency

Below is my very basic Lucene code

```
    private Document create(File file) throws IOException {
        Document document = new Document();

        Field field = new Field("contents", new FileReader(file), TextField.TYPE_NOT_STORED);
        Field fieldPath = new Field("path", file.getAbsolutePath(), TextField.TYPE_STORED);
        Field fieldName = new Field("name", file.getName(), TextField.TYPE_STORED);

        document.add(field);
        document.add(fieldPath);
        document.add(fieldName);

        //Create analyzer
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

        //Create IndexWriter pass the analyzer

        Path indexPath = Files.createTempDirectory("tempIndex");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath);
        IndexWriterConfig indexWriterCOnfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterCOnfig);
        iwriter.addDocument(document);
        iwriter.close();
        return document;
    }
```

Note : I understand the knowledge behind Lucene - the inverted index, but i lack the understanding of the lucene library uses this concept and how the files are created so that search was made easy and feasible using lucene.

I tried Limo, but of no use. Its just did not work even though i gave the index location in the web.xml

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to see a good introductory **code example**, using the current version of Lucene (building an index and then using it), you can start with the [basic demo](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_0/demo/index.html) (choose your version - this link is for Lucene 8.6).

The source code for the demo (using the latest version of Lucene) can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/apache/lucene/tree/main/lucene/demo).

If you would like to **explore your indexed data**, once it has been created, you can use Luke. In case you have not used it before: To run Luke, you need to download a *binary* release from the [main download page](https://lucene.apache.org/core/downloads.html). Unzip the file, and then navigate to the `luke` directory. Then run the relevant script (`luke.bat` or `luke.sh`).

(The only version of the `LIMO` tool I could find is [this one on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/limo/files/). Given it is from 2007, it is almost certainly no longer compatible with the latest Lucene index files. Maybe there is a more updated version somewhere.)

If you would like an **overview of the files** in a typical Lucene index, you can [start here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene86/package-summary.html#package.description).

Many specifc questions can be answered by looking at the [API documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_0/index.html) for relevant packages and classes.

Personally, I have also found the [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/) and [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) documentation to be very useful for explaining specific concepts, which are often directly relevant to Lucene.

Beyond that, I don't worry too much about how Lucene manages its internal index data structures. Instead I focus on the different types of analyzer and query which can be used to access that data.

---

**Update: SimpleTextCodec**

It is now a few months later, but here is one more way to explore Lucene's index data: [`SimpleTextCodec`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/codecs/org/apache/lucene/codecs/simpletext/SimpleTextCodec.html). The standard Lucene codec (how data is written to index files and read from them) uses a binary format - and is therefore not human readable. You can't just open an index file and see what's in there.

However, if you change the codec to `SimpleTextCodec`, then Lucene will create plain-text index files, where you can see the structure more clearly.

*This codec is provided purely for information/education, and should not be used in production.*

To use the codec, you first need to include the relevant dependency - for example, like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-codecs</artifactId>
    <version>8.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can use this new codec as follows:

```java
iwc.setCodec(new SimpleTextCodec());
```

So, for example:

```java
final String indexPath = "/path/to/index_dir";
final String docsPath = "/path/to/inputs_dir";
final Path docDir = Paths.get(docsPath);
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexPath));
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
iwc.setCodec(new SimpleTextCodec());
System.out.println(iwc.getCodec().getName());
try ( IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc)) {
    // read documents, and write index data:
    indexDocs(writer, docDir);
}
```

You are now free to inspect the resulting index files in a text reader (e.g. Notepad++).

In my case, the index data resulted in several files - but the one I was interested in here was my `*.scf` file - a "compound" file, containing various “virtual file” sections, where the human-readable index data was stored.

Answer (score 2):

If the index is large in size (e.g. hundreds of GBs), Luke sometimes fails to open it. There is a command-line based alternative of Luke, called `I-Rex`. It is developed for researches in Information Retrieval. Here is the link to it: https://github.com/souravsaha/I-REX/tree/shell-lucene8

Feel free to add/edit the codes.